# Docker - how to set up compose for local webserver

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker compose file in a local folder on my mac. I have also another folder /src which should act as the root element. The docker-compose file looks like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
    fpm:
        image: sbusso/php-fpm-ion
    nginx:
        image: nginx:stable
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        links:
            - fpm
            - db
    db:
        image: orchardup/mysql
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_DATABASE: myproject
```

I understand what we are doing here, but I am missing the solution that /src is taken as the root and I think I need to set up an lsync service which syncs between local and my docker container. So I found this one, but it is not working properly - the root /src is not taken into account. I just want to type localhost in my browser and it should open the /src folder.

```
version: '2'
services:
    fpm:
        image: sbusso/php-fpm-ion
        links:
            - sync
        volumes_from:
            - sync
    db:
        image: orchardup/mysql
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_DATABASE: myproject
        links:
            - sync
        volumes_from:
            - sync            
    nginx:
        image: nginx:stable
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        links:
            - sync
        volumes_from:
            - sync
    sync:
        image: zeroboh/lsyncd
        volumes:
            - /var/www/html
            - ./src:/src:Z
            - ./docker-config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            - /var/lib/php/session
            - ./docker-config/lrsync/lrsync.lua:/etc/lrsync/lrsync.lua
            - ./sync:/sync
```

What I do understand is that every image that is loaded links the sync service into it. What I do not understand is why every image needs a volumes_from and that the syntax in sync explicitly says - can somebody help me, setting this up correctly?

Thanks

Comment: Follow this example, then try yours 
https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/

Comment: Without `volumes_from`, none of the other containers would have access to the `sync` container's volumes. By default, each container has no volumes until you use either `volumes` or `volumes_from` to specify them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `volumes_from` imports volumes from another container

By default, each container has no volumes. You can define local volumes using the `volumes` attribute, but the volumes are only used in that container. In order for other containers to make use of them, those containers must import the volumes using `volumes_from`, pointing to the name of one or more containers. All volumes in those named containers are then made available in the current container.

### The `Z` volume label indicates a private volume

You are mounting the `/src` volume using this:

```
volumes:
    - ./src:/src:Z
```

That's fine, except you are also using `volumes_from`, and your question indicates that you specifically wanted to share `/src`. But by using the `Z` label, you have told Docker to make this a private volume.

From the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#/volume-labels):

> ### Volume labels
>
> Labeling systems like SELinux require that proper labels are placed on volume content mounted into a container. Without a label, the security system might prevent the processes running inside the container from using the content. By default, Docker does not change the labels set by the OS.
>
> To change a label in the container context, you can add either of two suffixes `:z` or `:Z` to the volume mount. These suffixes tell Docker to relabel file objects on the shared volumes. The z option tells Docker that two containers share the volume content. As a result, Docker labels the content with a shared content label. Shared volume labels allow all containers to read/write content. The Z option tells Docker to label the content with a private unshared label. Only the current container can use a private volume.

In this case, "current container" is `sync`, so only that container may use the volume. The others may not use it.